# Adding an independent (small) node in a mind map

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps

I used [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/computer-science-mindmap/) template, made some alterations and came up with following mind map:

[image: actual status]

The minimum working example (MWE) can be seen here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,paths.ortho,calc,paths.rectangle,positioning-plus,arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees,mindmap,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{
        \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
        level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=90},
        extra concept/.append style={color=blue!50,text=black}]
        \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
        node[concept] {Something}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child[concept color=green!50!black] {
            node[concept] (gov) {Something}
            [clockwise from=0]
            child { node[concept] (blub) {Something} }
            child { node[concept] (bla) {Something} }
            child { node[concept] (sep) {Something} }
            [clockwise from=-90]
            child { node[concept] (pau) {Something} }
        }  
        child[concept color=blue] {
            node[concept] (top) {Something}
        }
        child[concept color=red] { 
            node[concept] {Something} 
            [clockwise from=310]
            child { node[concept] (cot) {Something} }
            child { node[concept] (cont) {Something} }
        }
        child[concept color=orange] {
            node[concept] (gen) {Something} 
            [clockwise from=-180]
            child { node[concept] {Something} }
        };

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw [left color=blue, right color=green!50!black, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (pau) -- (top);
        \draw [left color=orange, right color=green!50!black, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (gen) -- (gov);
        \draw [left color=red, right color=blue, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (cot) -- (top);
        \draw [left color=red, right color=blue, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (cont) -- (top);
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

One feature of this MWE is that I have included all tikz libraries that I use in my tex file as well as the `\resizebox`. Please let me know if this does not add any helpful information.

I now want to add an independent node of approximately the same size as the other smaller nodes. What I have in mind looks something like this:

[image: target status]

I am aware that [this](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/scientific-interactions/) template exists. However, the second independent node would be horribly big. Does anyone have suggestions on how to solve this. I would dearly appreciate it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `extra concept` style for the additional node (this is the exact situation for which the style was designed) and draw the lines with a loop:

```
\node[fill=blue,circle,font=\scriptsize,extra concept,text=white]
  (additional)
  at (blub|-pau)
 {Something else};
\foreach \Name in {blub,sep,bla}
  \draw[dashed,ultra thick,blue] (additional) -- (\Name);
```

The result:

[image]

The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,,arrows.meta,shapes,positioning,shadows,trees,mindmap,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[mindmap,
        level 1 concept/.append style={level distance=130,sibling angle=90},
        extra concept/.append style={color=blue!50,text=black}]
        \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white]
        node[concept] {Something}
        [clockwise from=0]
        child[concept color=green!50!black] {
            node[concept] (gov) {Something}
            [clockwise from=0]
            child { node[concept] (blub) {Something} }
            child { node[concept] (bla) {Something} }
            child { node[concept] (sep) {Something} }
            [clockwise from=-90]
            child { node[concept] (pau) {Something} }
        }  
        child[concept color=blue] {
            node[concept] (top) {Something}
        }
        child[concept color=red] { 
            node[concept] {Something} 
            [clockwise from=310]
            child { node[concept] (cot) {Something} }
            child { node[concept] (cont) {Something} }
        }
        child[concept color=orange] {
            node[concept] (gen) {Something} 
            [clockwise from=-180]
            child { node[concept] {Something} }
        };

        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw [left color=blue, right color=green!50!black, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (pau) -- (top);
        \draw [left color=orange, right color=green!50!black, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (gen) -- (gov);
        \draw [left color=red, right color=blue, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (cot) -- (top);
        \draw [left color=red, right color=blue, draw=white, decorate,decoration=circle connection bar] (cont) -- (top);
        \end{pgfonlayer}

\node[fill=blue,circle,font=\scriptsize,extra concept,text=white]
  (additional)
  at (blub|-pau)
 {Something else};
\foreach \Name in {blub,sep,bla}
  \draw[dashed,ultra thick,blue] (additional) -- (\Name);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}


\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

As a side note, using `[!h]` as float position specifier is a recipe for disaster; use a less restrictive option such as `[!htp]` or, better yet, none at all.